# 2001 Audi A4 just got really loud

Tags: exhaust, noise, audi, muffler

Alright, So I'm driving to work. I'm stopped at the red light to go on the freeway. It turns green so I accelerate. I'm accelerating more than I would on a regular street but I didn't floor it. Anyway, all of a sudden my exhaust sounded REALLY loud.  It sounds like I have no muffler or something. I pull in to a gas station but my muffler is still there. It's loud at idle and gets louder the more I push down on the pedal.  The sound sounds like it's coming from under the driver's feet.  I looked under the car where I think the noise is coming from and I didn't really see anything. It looks like a bolt may be missing from about the same spot the noise is coming from but I don't know if it's related or just a coincidence.  I don't remember hearing anything falling off my car when it happened.  No warning lights or anything.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a cracked/rusted out weld somewhere.  Could be a hole that finally rusted through.  Sometimes the bolted together joints rust through.  Typically results in a cat-back exhaust replacement.  Can end up being full system replacement.  Rarely can be fixed in just one location.

Comment: Will it damage my car to drive it home (50 miles)?

Comment: Impossible to say for certain, especially without knowing the *exact* cause/location.  Generally speaking, the risk of damage is low for this type of thing.  Unfortunately, the modes of failure that you *are* exposed to (while not real likely) are pretty nasty (hot exhaust burning through something/setting something on fire, parts dropping from your car and jamming into the roadway causing control problems, parts falling off and hitting a car behind you, etc.).  Also, there's the risk of getting an excessive noise traffic ticket to consider as well.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, it is likely a hole in your exhaust.  I have a 99 A4 and get an exhaust leak about once a year by the flex pipe near the front.  If a CEL didn't come on, I couldn't imagine something mechanically wrong that would cause it.  Easy way to check is to jack the car up or put it on a lift while running and see if you feel air being blown somewhere along the exhaust.  **DON'T TOUCH THE EXHAUST**, it will burn you.  Just run your hand 6-12inches away.